# Implementing ThrowingFunction like Function in java

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

In our project I wanted to use Function in my method but sins the reference method is throwing exception then I looked to Function interface for creating my ThrowingFunction like this so the question here is did I implemented the interface in correct way inf default methods and can this implementation cause side effects or errors?
Is this interface safe to use instead of java Function interface? because I implemented it from *`java.util.function.Function`* interface that java doesn't have Function like this so I am not sure abut that!

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {

    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     * 
     * @param t the function argument
     * @return the function result
     * @throws E the function throwing exception
     */
    R apply(T t) throws E;

    default <V> ThrowingFunction<V, R, E> compose(ThrowingFunction<? super V, ? extends T, E> before) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(before);
        return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
    }

    default <V> ThrowingFunction<T, V, E> andThen(ThrowingFunction<? super R, ? extends V, E> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
    }

    static <T, E extends Exception> ThrowingFunction<T, T, E> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the "correct way"?

Comment: Well for example I am not sure if we can use default methods in java stream API and I am worry about using it in production project in stream API !

Comment: If your function throws a checked exception it is recommended that you catch and handle it properly. But if you just pass it on in this kind of interface, chances are high that the caller doesn't know how to handle this exception (otherwise you would use a regular interface and not this style. So my advice would be that you handle checked exceptions properly inside your function and only throw unchecked exceptions (inherit from `RuntimeException`), they should not need this trick.